# WCF - calling a void service (is it still synchronous)?

Tags: wcf, void, synchronous, faultexception

Basically, if my service is: `public void DoSomethingThatTakesAwhile() { ... }`, will the call to that service cause my application to wait for the method to finish?

I ask because I don't want my caller to be able to continue until that method finishes in case the method needs to throw a fault exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the call is synchronous, unless the operation is marked with [OperationContract(**IsOneWay = true**)]

Comment: I think it would be be more accurate to say "Yes, your application will wait for the method to finish"...synchronous is a bit misleading because a one-way operation can still block.